# Regex for prosodically-defined words: working in Atom but not grep

Tags: regex, bash, macos, grep, linguistics

I'm trying to search a .txt dictionary for all trisyllabic roots, and then have the matching roots passed to a new .txt file. The dictionary in question is a raw text version of Heath's Nunggubuyu dictionary. When I search the file in Atom (my preferred text editor), the following string does a pretty good job of singling out the desired roots and eliminating any material from the definitions below the headwords (which begin with whitespace), as well as any English words, and any trisyllabic strings interrupted by a hyphen or equals sign (which mean they are not monomorphemic roots). Forgive me if it looks clunky; I'm an absolute beginner. (In this orthography, vowel length is indicated with a ':', and there are only three vowels 'a,i,u'. None of the headwords have uppercase letters.)

```
^\S[^aeiousf]*[aiu:]+[^csfaioeu:\-\=\W]+[aiu:]+[^VNcsfaeiou:\-\=]+[aiu:]+[^VcsfNaeiou:]*\b
```

However, I need the matched strings to be output to a new file. When I try using this same string in grep (on a Mac), nothing is matched. I use the syntax

```
grep -o "^\S[^aeiousf]*[aiu:]+[^csfaioeu:\-\=\W]+[aiu:]+[^VNcsfaeiou:\-\=]+[aiu:]+[^VcsfNaeiou:]*\b" Dict-nofrontmatter.txt > output.txt
```

I've been searching for hours trying to figure out how to translate from Atom's regex dialect to grep (Mac), to no avail. Whenever I do manage to get matches, the results looks wildly different to what I expect, and what I get from Atom. I've also looked at some apparent grep tools for Atom, but the documentation is virtually non-existent so I can't work out what they even do. What am I getting wrong here? Should I try an alternative to grep?

Comment: In my experience, grep regex needs backslash before special characters to use them. Usually you need backslash to escape a character... I also observed that in find on some Unix distro...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the only thing missing from your `grep` command is the `-E` option:

```
regex='^\S[^aeiousf]*[aiu:]+[^csfaioeu:\-\=\W]+[aiu:]+[^VNcsfaeiou:\-\=]+[aiu:]+[^VcsfNaeiou:]*\b'
grep -Eo "$regex" Dict-nofrontmatter.txt > output.txt
```

`-E` activates support for *extended* (modern) regular expressions, which work as one expects nowadays (duplication symbols `+` and `?` work as expected, `(` and `)` form capture groups, `|` is alternation).

Without `-E` (or with `-G`) *basic* regular expressions are assumed - a limited legacy form that differs in syntax. Given that [`-E` is part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html), there's no reason *not* to use it.

On macOS, `grep` *does* understand character-class shortcuts such as `\S` and `\W`, and also word-boundary assertions such as `\b` - this is in contrast with the other BSD utilities that macOS comes with, notably `sed` and `awk`.

---

It doesn't look like you need it, but [PRCEs (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions)](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html) would provide additional features, such as [look-around assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

macOS `grep` doesn't support them, but *GNU* `grep` does, via the `-P` option. You can install GNU `grep` on macOS via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Alternatively, you can simply use `perl` directly; the equivalent of the above command would be:

```
regex='^\S[^aeiousf]*[aiu:]+[^csfaioeu:\-\=\W]+[aiu:]+[^VNcsfaeiou:\-\=]+[aiu:]+[^VcsfNaeiou:]*\b'
perl -lne "print for m/$regex/g" Dict-nofrontmatter.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: That worked pretty much perfectly, and the explanation was helpful. Thank you!

Comment: @PeterNyhuisTorres: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` supports different regex styles. From `man re_format`:

> Regular  expressions ("RE"s), as defined in POSIX.2, come in two
>   forms:
>   modern REs (roughly those of egrep; POSIX.2 calls these *extended* REs) and
>   obsolete REs (roughly those of ed(1); POSIX.2 *basic* REs).

Grep has switches to choose which variant is used. Sorted from less to many features:

**fixed string:** `grep -F` or `fgrep`
No regex at all. Plain text search.

**basic regex:** `grep -G` or just `grep`
`|`, `+`,  and  `?` are ordinary characters. `|` has no equivalent. Parentheses must be escaped to work as sub-expressions.

**extended regex:** `grep -E` or `egrep`
"Normal" regexes with `|`, `+`, `?` *bounds* and so on.

**perl regex:** `grep -P` (for GNU grep, not pre-installed on Mac)
Most powerful regexes. Supports lookaheads and other features.

In your case you should try `grep -Eo "^\S...`.